# How to create landscape strings.xml for other languages

Tags: android, localization, orientation

How to create a folder with for example strings-de.xml file for a landscape orientation mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the resources folders `values-XX-land\`.

For example:

```
values-it-land\strings.xml
```

You can check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources):

> Android supports several configuration qualifiers and you can add multiple qualifiers to one directory name, by **separating each qualifier with a dash**. Table 2 lists the valid configuration qualifiers, **in order of precedence**—if you use multiple qualifiers for a resource directory, you must add **them to the directory name in the order they are listed in the table**.